# How to design routes for generalized/specialized resources

Tags: design, architecture, rest

I hope I can explain what is troubling me.

Example: I have an object basket with a list of fruit objects. So normally I would build my routes like this baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId). But fruit is an interface and there are different implementations like apples and oranges that all require their own resource representation.

So how do I build my routes now?

Like one of those?:

- baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId}/apple,
  baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId)/orange and so on
- baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId}/apples/{fruitId} ,
  baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId}/oranges/{fruitId}
- baskets/{basketId}/apples/{fruitId},
  baskets/{basketId}/oranges/{fruitId}

What would be the restful way?

Comment: Don't *different fruit implementations* imply *different media types*?

Comment: why should an apple have an different media type than a banana?

Comment: I guess for the same reason that a gif image should have a different media type (`image/gif`) than a jpeg (`image/jpeg`). Unless I'm missing something, that is...

Comment: yes but should I implement a custom media type for every object that I use? The media type will be JSON for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The point of an interface is to hide the fact that there are different possible implementations. When you sit in a restaurant, basically you care only that you'll get service from *someone*. You may or may not be aware that you might get service from Jose, Marcia, or Stephanie, and you *definitely* don't want to have to do different things in order to get the same cheeseburger from different waiters. Your view of the transaction as a consumer is "get a cheeseburger", not "talk to Jose"/"talk to Marcia"/"talk to Stephanie".

If the consumer has to know about all the possible implementations, and which one he wants to access, then for purposes of your API you might just as well not have an interface, since you're not actually saving the effort that it's supposed to save. It can still be useful to make details of the implementation easier, but as long as the difference between the alternative object classes is externally visible, the interface ceases to be a useful API component.

Comment: But the user wants to get a fruit and than interact with the fruit in the fruit specific way. If I order breakfast I will handle my egg different than my bread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the fruits, apples, oranges, and so one, all have fruit ids. So if you want to reference a specific fruit in a basket, then:

> /baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId)

is still valid. However, if the "fruitId" is unique, it would me much better to just use

> /fruits/{fruitId)

However, if you only want to see certain types of fruits in a basket, then you can take advantage of the query string in it's role of "narrowing" the resource:

> baskets/{basketId}?fruits=mango

or

> baskets/{basketId}?fruits=apple&fruits=banana

Once you get that list of items, each should have it's own ID & you can get them individually if you like.

From a RESTful point of view, there are two resources here:

- a *collection* of the fruits in a given basket
- an individual fruit

Use the query string to limit the *collection* resource, and use the (shorter) fruitId once you know which specific one you want.

BTW The problem remains the same if you are selecting fruits from someone's hat:

> /hat/{hatId}?fruits=bananas&fruits=pineapples

EDIT: (taken from comments so it will be more readable)

To add an apple

> POST /basket/{id}
>
> (the apple representation)

POST is often considered the "append" verb, but you could use PUT. Note that you're appending the apple to the basket collection, so you use the collection URI.

To find the apples in the basket:

> GET /basket/{id}?fruits=apple

EDIT EDIT: If you have some other code/value/attribute in mind, just support that in the query string:

> GET /basket/{id}?color=red

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow you missed my problem. I need to access the concrete fruits as a concrete resource due to different code/validation/attributes etc so basket/{id}/fruits/{fruitId} is not going to work. I could do a redirect from there but how does the path look like I redirect to...

Comment: Like I say, that sounds like a query string rather than the front part of the URI. The URI is an identifier, and the "searchable part" -- the query string -- narrows the results based on code/validation/attributes etc.

Comment: Then how would you add an apple to the fruits in the basket?

Comment: shouldn't it be POST /basket/{id}/fruits?fruit=apple ? But besides that than my fruit resource would have to be gigantic to handle each fruit, wouldn't it?

Comment: The trailing "/fruits" seems redundant. I don't see why the fruit resource would be huge... how big is a basket? How much data do you have about a fruit?

Comment: A basket contains more than fruits. Fruit wise there are a lot of fruits which are completely different from each other besides the point that they are fruit.

Answer (score 0):

The most RESTful way would probably be to define separate routes for each fruit type:

```
baskets/{basketId}/apples
baskets/{basketId}/apples/{appleId}
baskets/{basketId}/bananas
baskets/{basketId}/bananas/{fruitId}
... other fruits
```

And use a different media type for each fruit, e.g.:

```
application/vnd.com.example.apple+json
application/vnd.com.example.banana+json
```

In this case you would need to request a list of every possible type and handle them individually.

A less RESTful solution might be to treat fruit as the interface that it sounds like it is, and just get a list of them.

```
baskets/{basketId}/fruits
baskets/{basketId}/fruits/{fruitId}
```

Since JSON is usually schema-less, each item can look completely different, and you could use some identifying characteristic to map each to the specific fruit class which understands its JSON representation and contains its behavior.